# Improving runtime when finding nonzero streaks in a list

Tags: python, runtime, bioinformatics

I have written a function that takes in a list of integers and a value l. The return value is a tuple--the first element being the count of integer streaks (must be length l or longer) that include nonzeros, the second being the average length of those streaks. I am using this function for a bioinformatics project that will require me to have input of lists that hold millions of integers. I am finding that the method I wrote is just too slow. How can I improve the efficiency of my program?

```
def contigs_values(sequenced_lst, l):
    """
    By splitting at zeros, can count contiguous sequenced sequences
    """
    # a list of lists storing index start and end values of each contig
    contig_indices = []

    start = 0
    end = 1
    while end != len(sequenced_lst):
        if 0 not in sequenced_lst[start:end + 1]:  # only extend window if contiguous
            end += 1  # extend contig window
            # continue
            if end == len(sequenced_lst):
                contig_indices.append([start, end])  # append final contig indices as index list
        else:  # zero is found and contig broken
            if end - start > 1:
                if end - start < l:  # debug test... TODO: no window should be less than R length, L
                    print("MISTAKE")
                contig_indices.append([start, end])  # append contig indices as index list
            start = end  # start a new contig window
            end += 1
    num_contigs = len(contig_indices)
    avg_contig_len = get_average([i[1] - i[0] for i in contig_indices])

    return num_contigs, avg_contig_len
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the goal correctly, the reason your code runs so slowly is that you are constantly checking the length of a list, so somewhere in the neighborhood of O(n^2)
So instead of calculating the length of the list, find the difference between the current 0 and the previous 0.
It's relatively easy using enumerate:

```
def contigs_values(sequenced_lst, l):
    """
    By splitting at zeros, can count contiguous sequenced sequences
    """
    streaks = []

    prev = 0
    for index, val in enumerate(sequenced_lst):
        if val == 0:
            length = index - prev - 1
            if length >= l:
                streaks.append(length)
            prev = index
    else:
        if index - prev >= l:
            streaks.append(index - prev)
    

    num_contigs = len(streaks)
    avg_contig_len = sum(streaks)/num_contigs

    return num_contigs, avg_contig_len
```